# Meta tag broken HTML in CKEditor 4.5.6

Tags: ckeditor

Problem: when I append Meta tag, I see:

```
<div class="news_video div_video20151128141055" id="video-schema" item-prop="video" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
<div id="video-schema-meta">
<div> </div>
</div>
</div>
<meta content="Video" itemprop="description" />
```

But it must be:

```
  <div class="news_video div_video20151128141055" id="video-schema" item-prop="video" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
<div id="video-schema-meta">
<div><meta content="Video" itemprop="description" /> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

However, if I change META to DIV, all works correctly.
Similar problem was earlier, but it was fixed (https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8117)
And now I don't know what should I do. Maybe I doing something wrong?